# replace a character in a string using at function?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string CorrAns = "Text", I want to replace a character at a particular position with a character from another string.
I used the following:

```
CorrAns.replace(1,1,OtherString.at(pos));
```

But its giving error, what is the best way to do this??

Comment: *But it's giving error* - That doesn't help much.

Comment: Like chris says, saying it gives an error is not much to go on, you need to edit your question to add the actual error. And it would be best if you used copy-paste to get the whole output from your compiler.

Comment: @Swapp Sawant if you want help, you have to be bit more elaborate in framing your question.

Comment: I agree that he should at least tell use the error, but in this case, it's rather obvious what's wrong: `std::string::at()` returns a `char&`, and the third argument to `std::string::replace` should be a string of some sort, not a `char`.

Comment: sorry for that .. error is same as @JamesKanze has mentioned. I found the answer below. Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` has no overload taking `size, size, char`.  You want

```
CorrAns.replace(1, 1, 1, OtherString.at(pos));
```

or

```
CorrAns.replace(1, 1, OtherString.substr(pos, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `at` (or the `[]` operator) accross the board:

```
corrAns[1] = otherString[pos];
```

(Note that `at` rarely has the semantics you want.  If a bounds error is
a precondition failure, as is usually the case, the last thing you want
is an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. There are several methods for replace() function. Check below :

http://www.ansatt.hig.no/frodeh/ooprog/string2.html

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this would be:

```
CorrAns[1] = OtherString[pos];
```

If you insist on using the replace function, check out  [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/). One correct call would look like:

```
CorrAns.replace(1, 1, 1, OtherString.at(pos));
```